# Django session countdown timer

Tags: django, templates, session, timer, countdown

I have it in my login screen:

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1200 # 20 minutes

And I want to show the remaining time in my template

Does anyone know a good or middleware package for django to add a timer remaining to end the login session. I did not think anything built with Django, just javascript solutions. Thank U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the session key from the request. Then, it's easy to get the session object and query its age:

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

session_key = request.COOKIES["sessionid"]
session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)

remaining_seconds = session.get_expiry_age()
```

Then you must add `remaining_seconds` variable to your template context or maybe better write a context processor so this variable is available at every template.

Comment: Exactly, except for the method to get the time, getting that changed:

time = session.expire_date()

With ajax I take this value and using a jquery countdown I show in the template.

Comment: I am getting error `'Session' object has no attribute 'get_expiry_age'`. Checked the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/sessions/). Am I missing something?

Comment: @carla `Session` is the class, it doesn't have that attribute or method. You must get the session object the way I shown above :)

Comment: Sorry, I got it. (I was missing the `request` part). Thanks.